# Que esta mal en la consulta php admin

Tags: phpmyadmin

EL GESTOR ES MYSQL PHP ADMIN, QUIERO HACER ESTA CONSULTA CON PARÁMETROS

```
CREATE PROCEDURE VALIDAR_USUARIO (IN nombre varchar(20), IN contraseña varchar(50) )
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE usuario.User = nombre AND usuario.Pass= contraseña ;
END
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bievenido a Stackoverflow. En la mayoría de casos, como es este precisamente, habría ayudado más que pongas el texto del código que una imagen. Puedes [editar la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/174602/edit) cambiando la imagen por el texto. Además, en un principio la imagen ni siquiera se veía. También, evita el USO DE TODO MAYÚSCULAS. Es desagradable en este medio. En cuanto al problema en sí, conviene que indiques si está dando algún error y qué dice el mensaje de error. Saludos

Comment: Creo que lo que buscas es retornar registros de tabla completos, los procedimientos almacenados se suelen usar para ejecutar acciones en la base de datos (insert, updates o deletes), en este caso te serviría más usar una función con un return.

Answer (score 0):

deberias revisar la documentacion de Maria DB [aquí](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-procedure/), para crearlo se hace asi, el begin y el end no son comandos reconocidos ahora.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getlogin`(
    p_usuario VARCHAR(20),
    p_clave VARCHAR(50)
    )
SELECT  id_usuario
    FROM usuario 
    WHERE usuario = p_usuario  
      AND clave = p_clave$$
DELIMITER ;
```